# kdb+/q: Prevent initialised tables from returning a comma

Tags: kdb

Consider the following example:

```
test:([] name:`symbol$(); secondColumn:`int$());
insert[`test;(`John;1)];
myvar:exec name from test;
```

Now `myvar` is now:

```
q)myvar
,`John
```

So to select the *actual* result, I have to do:

```
q)myvar[0]
`John
```

I understand this is because of the initialisation, so is there a way to make `myvar` contain the actual value immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array access with `[0]` or `first` is the correct way if you want an "atomic" variable.

```
myvar:first exec name from test;
```

Answer (score 1):

A list with a single element in KDB can be created in multiple ways (which is something you are getting in `myvar`)

```
q)enlist `John
,`John
q)(),`John
,`John
```

A KDB table is basically a `flip` of a dictionary of lists.

```
`name`secondColumn!(`John`James;1 2)  /Dictionary of lists
name        | John James
secondColumn| 1    2

q)test2:flip `name`secondColumn!(`John`James;1 2)
name  secondColumn
------------------
John  1
James 2
```

Both of the following commands achieve the same results :

```
q)exec name from test2
q)test2[`name]
`John`James
```

When you selected the `test` column using the `exec` command it returned all the elements of the list (a list with one element)

Apart from the ways explained in the accepted answer, there are few more ways (slightly different however) you can get the first element returned from the table.

```
q)exec name[0] from test
q)test[`name][0]
q)exec first name from test
```